# Populating a treeview with files in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, treenode, directoryinfo

I have a treeview that I am trying to populate with folders and files. The treeview is populating the folders just fine but not the files. Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                PopulateTree();
            }              

        }

private void PopulateTree()
        {
            //Populate the tree based on the subfolders of the specified VirtualImageRoot
            var rootFolder = new DirectoryInfo(VirtualImageRoot);
            var root = AddNodeAndDescendents(rootFolder, null);

            //Add the root to the TreeView
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(root);
        }

private TreeNode AddNodeAndDescendents(DirectoryInfo folder, TreeNode parentNode)
        {
            //Add the TreeNode, displaying the folder's name and storing the full path to the folder as the value...
            string virtualFolderPath;

            if (parentNode == null)
            {
                virtualFolderPath = VirtualImageRoot;
            }
            else
            {
                virtualFolderPath = parentNode.Value + folder.Name + "/";
            }

            var node = new TreeNode(folder.Name, virtualFolderPath);

            //Recurse through this folder's subfolders
            var subFolders = folder.GetDirectories();

            foreach (DirectoryInfo subFolder in subFolders)
            {
                var child = AddNodeAndDescendents(subFolder, node);

                foreach (FileInfo file in subFolder.GetFiles())
                {

                    var index = file.FullName.LastIndexOf(@"\", StringComparison.Ordinal);
                    var strname = file.FullName.Substring(index + 1);
                    var name = strname.Split('.');

                    var tn = new TreeNode();
                    if (name.Length > 1 && name[1].ToLower() == "bch")
                    {
                        tn = new TreeNode(name[0], file.FullName);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tn = new TreeNode(name[0], file.FullName);
                    }
                    child.ChildNodes.Add(tn);
                }
                node.ChildNodes.Add(child);

            }
            //Return the new TreeNode
            return node;
        }
```

Here is what my tree looks like:

[image: My Tree View: without files]

Here is a picture of the files in the folder:

[image: My files]

I am trying just to show the files with the type .bch, along with the folders in my treeview. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your Substring hurts my brain. Did you know that FileInfo has an Extension property?

Comment: @Biscuits No, I didn't know that

Comment: Ok. Nevertheless, I would opt to use the GetFiles overload on DirectoryInfo that allows you to specify the search pattern upfront.

Comment: @Biscuits Can you give me an example in code?

Comment: foreach (FileInfo file in subFolder.GetFiles("*.bch"))

Comment: The code works more or less ok. I've just tried. The fishy part is the if-else where both the branches do the same...

Comment: @rocky I still can't get it to work right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that your code didn't take into account the first level of the folder hierarchy:

```
private void PopulateTree()
{
    var rootFolder = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\yourwebproject");
    var root = AddNodeAndDescendents(rootFolder);
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add(root);
}

private TreeNode AddNodeAndDescendents(DirectoryInfo folder)
{        
    var node = new TreeNode(folder.Name, folder.Name);

    var subFolders = folder.GetDirectories();

    foreach (DirectoryInfo subFolder in subFolders)
    {
        var child = AddNodeAndDescendents(subFolder);
        node.ChildNodes.Add(child);
    }

    foreach (FileInfo file in folder.GetFiles("*.bch"))
    {
        var tn = new TreeNode(file.Name, file.FullName);
        node.ChildNodes.Add(tn);
    }
    return node;
}
```

Comment: I just tried your code, I am still just getting the folders, no files. Am I missing something?

Comment: Then I think the problem is that the extension is not really .bch. Try following: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/show-hide-file-name-extensions#show-hide-file-name-extensions=windows-7

Comment: No it really is the file extension. I am going to post a pic of the files for you.

Comment: What happens when you put a breakpoint on the line "var tn =..."? Is it ever hit?

Comment: Aren't those files marked as hidden? (However GetFiles() should return even hidden files)

Comment: I see what the problem is now...You're not adding files from the first level  :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74885/discussion-between-nate-and-rocky).